# Same temp table has created by different session and occurs blocking issue. how to avoid it?

Tags: sql-server-2012, tempdb, blocking

It's a SQL Server 2012 EE.

One session (SID=90) executed a JOIN query, and it's generated a temp table internally by SQL Server.

But another sessions (SID=103, 109, 110,116) from totally different app ran a query, and blocked by above session due to the same temp table!

As a result several blocking occurred. (Pls refer to the screenshot)
How it could be happened? I can't understand and lost mind how to fix it.
[image]

The first session executed:

```
SELECT ... FROM Institution institutio0_ 
left outer join ImageFile imagefile1_ 
on institutio0_.ImageFileId=imagefile1_.Id 
WHERE institutio0_.Id=@p0
```

And blocked sessions executed a same query:

```
select EventClass, LoginName, StartTime, FileName, ObjectID, IndexID, ObjectType, ObjectName, EventSubClass, Success, case when ParentName is not null then ParentName else OwnerName end as OwnerName, .... SCHEMA_NAME( OBJECTPROPERTY( ObjectID, 'SchemaId' ) ) DerivedOwnerName, OBJECT_NAME( ObjectID ) DerivedObjectName 
from ::fn_trace_gettable(  @P0 , default ) 
where StartTime >  @P1  
and StartTime <=  @P2  
and DatabaseID =  @P3
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are both sessions using the same temp table?

Comment: @McNets  Yes, that's my question, how it's possible? The first one is a long running OUTER JOIN query, and system create the temp table. And second query, too.  But both are same name of temp table!

Comment: Can't you change the name of one of them?

Comment: @McNets No. The temp table name is internally created by sql server engine when the JOIN query was running. But the blocked sessions, I have no idea how/why try to lock the same temp table.

Comment: Is there any stored procedure involved?

Comment: @jelongpark Are you 100% sure about that description? Are you sure that you are looking at the correct statement(s)? I've never heard of JOINs creating user temp tables. Something doesn't seem right about this.